# Using R to simulate a sampling distribution under $H_0$

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, self-study

> We wonder if the colors (of which there are 6) in “Fun Pack” of M & Ms are distributed at random. Let us define as our test statistic $T$ (and there are many ways we could choose to do this) as the minimum number of candies of any color.
>
> a) Write out the null and alternative hypothesis.
>   b) What would be evidence for the alternative: large values of $T$ or small values of $T$?
>   c) Simulate the sampling distribution of $T$ when we open a pack that contains 24 candies and report the probabilities that $T = 0;1;2;3;4$. Hint: `x <- sample(1:6, size=24, replace=TRUE)` will get you a random sample of “colors” for a pack (e.g., red = 1, orange = 2, etc.), and `min(tabulate(x, nbins=6))` will give the minimum # seen over all colors.
>   d) We open a pack and find that there is only one yellow (and plenty of the other colors). What is the p-value of your test statistic and your conclusion regarding the null hypothesis.
>   e) If we take a = 5%, is there any possible combination of colors that will result in us rejecting the null hypothesis?

So far I have the null hypothesis being M&Ms picked at random. The smaller the value of $T$, the more evidence we have that it is not random and the larger the value of $T$ the more evidence we have that it is random. I know I need to simulate a sampling distribution of $T$ in `R` but am having a hard time doing so correctly. I know I need to somehow manipulate this code:

```
T <- c()               # initialize test statistic 
for (i in 1:1000) {    # do 1000 trials 
 counter <- 0 
 viewed  <- rep(0,200) # vector for number of times pic has been viewed
 T[i]    <- counter
} 
table(T)
```

But am not sure how to do so correctly to fit the problem. This will give me the chart output in `R`.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Would you like to revise it in the light of the guidelines [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)?

Comment: This is clearly routine bookwork. In fact it looks like you're *asking us to do your assignment*. Please add the `self-study` tag, and (as @TooTone already suggested), revise your question to fit with the the guidelines on that sort of question. In particular, you don't get to just post your assigned work and expect us to do it for you; if you meet the community expectations on this sort of question (to begin by showing what you've already done and where your problems lie), you can get guidance and helpful hints. (If you leave the question as is it will very likely be closed.)

Comment: What is it you want the code to do, exactly? It sounds like you have `a` & `b`, the problem explicitly asks you to simulate for `c`, so maybe that's where you are? But `c` gives you some code to start w/ & you aren't using that in the code you list, so I'm not sure where you are or what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

From where it appears you are, you need to insert the two snippets the professor gave you into the loop.

```
                   # initialize test statistic
                   #it should be a vector with a place for each iteration of your loop
T <- rep(NA,1000)      
                   # do 1000 trials 
for (i in 1:1000) {    
                   #this is what you were given to create one sample
    x <- sample(1:6, size=24, replace=TRUE)
                   #this is what you were given to extract the statistic from a sample
                   #make sure to put it into the ith place in the vector
    T[i]=min(tabulate(x, nbins=6))
}
```

Then you should look at T and see if it is anything like what you want.